# Calling javascript function from Codebehind doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following snippet in my aspx codebhind:

```
private void setUploadVisible()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("set Upload script");
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(),
    DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(),
    "uploadVisible();",
    true);
}
```

The first log gets printed, however I get an

> Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadVisible is not defined

I have another function in my JS file, besides this one, that gets called the same way from my aspx file and it works correctly.
Any idea why this one doesn't get called?
I have placed a `console.log`in the first line of the function and it doesn't get printed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post code from ASPX page?

Comment: This has nothing to do with aspnet or the ScriptManager. `uploadVisible()` does not exist in the front-end javascript code.

Comment: I guess `uploadVisible()` is a custom JS function, if it exists inside external JS file you should include it first. But if it exist on the same page, probably the function is not yet loaded when function call is initiated.